# Piping commands in plink on windows command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line, putty, plink

I am using Python to automate installation of rpms on a linux box. i m using plink to connect to the linux box. First I need to get the info of already installed certain rpms on the box. for this i am the command

```
os.system('plink root@server -pw pass rpm -qa|grep string > rpm.txt')
```

Here the command line interpreters the `'|'` as a cmd command and throws the error
"grep is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Also the `rpm.txt` is created on my machine instead on the linux box.

Anyway i can use the `'|'` and also makesure that `'rmp.txt'` is created in the linux box?

Comment: did you try escaping the |?

Comment: @amadain yeah i tried escaping the '|' but still the same thing happens

Comment: what about ff=subprocess.Popen("plink root@server -pw pass rpm -qa",shell=False,stdin=subprocess.PIPE) ff.communicate("grep string > rpm.txt")  ?

Comment: pity I didn't put it as an answer

Comment: I put it as an answer so that someone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ff=subprocess.Popen("plink root@server -pw pass rpm -qa",shell=False,stdin=subprocess.PIPE) 
ff.communicate("grep string > rpm.txt")
```

A